# Fresh Snap Install of PyCharm 2020.2.1 Won't Debug

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a fresh install of Pycharm 2020.2.1 that won't debug. I installed this on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I'm using a python 3.8 configuration.

I run the debugger and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/209/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2141, in <module>
    main()
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/209/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1975, in main
    setup = process_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/209/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_command_line_handling.py", line 136, in process_command_line
    setup['file'] = argv[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And then I get a "Connection to Python debugger failed" message.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: The error is in the line `setup['file'] = argv[i]`, somewhere you have a functional error which is causing `i` to exceed the length of the list.

Comment: @AnuragReddy, thanks but any ideas of how to solve this problem. I'm looking at the elif in the file but I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

Comment: I cannot comment for sure unless I get to see your code.

Comment: @AnuragReddy the python code is a simple `print("Hello")`. This is literally the first thing I've done after the install.

Comment: that is interesting, would probably post that in jetbrains forum and see what they have to say there.

Comment: Just created one [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009736500-Connection-to-Python-debugger-failed-Socket-closed-IndexError-list-index-out-of-range-)